# Inline Code on Webform Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, inline-code

Why doesn't this display the date/time when rendered?

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="test" Text="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" ></asp:Label>
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

Asp.net server controls don't play well with the <%=, instead you can do:

```
<span><%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></span>
```

Ps. you could alternatively set the label's text on the code-behind. It might work for your scenario to set it on the PreRenderComplete.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you've got a code behind file, but if you really need to set the label's `Text` property in the .aspx markup you could add the following code to the page:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.test.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            base.OnPreLoad(e);
        }
    }
</script>
```

This way you can maintain the label control's state on postback.

Comment: I don't have a code behind or a designer file this is an MVC view page, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the inline code inside the label's tag as below,

```
< asp:Label ID="Lbl" runat="server" Text="">
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
< /asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the asp tags are rendered.  You will have to set the property at runtime. or just do the `<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>`.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here though is I need to set the property of a WebControl with code on the markup page.  The only way I've found to do this is put the whole control in a code block.  Its not elegant or suggested but when all else fails this will work.

```
    <%
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
        var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        var label = new Label { Text = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
        label.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        Response.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
     %>
```

But this won't work if you need the control to maintain state.

UPDATE:

After researching Kev's answer I did find an even better solution.  I don't have a code behind (its an MVC page) but you can still reference a control on the page through a code block so my new solution is the following.  Note - You have to place the code block first for this to work.

```
 <%
    lblTest.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
 %>
<asp:label runat="server" ID="lblTest" />
```

Thanks for the inspiration Kev!

Comment: In that case, I still like better to add it on the codebehind, perhaps on the PreRenderComplete (added that comment to my answer) - or even Render (not sure if the label would grab the value, if you set it before doing base.OnRender )

Comment: @Chief7 - you might want to add the MVC tag to the question, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make that work would be to use a data-binding expression in place of the code render block...

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="test" Text="<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" ></asp:Label>
```

Now the Text property will be set whenever Page.DataBind() is called, so in your code-behind you'll want something like

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBind();
    }

   base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Comment: PLEASE encourage folks to use test.DataBind() and not this.DataBind(). No need for all the controls to go through the DataBinding events if unecessary.