# Inline Code in markup page in ASP.NET Webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, inline-code

Is something similiar to the following pseduocode possible on server side controls?

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text=<%=DateTime.Now.ToString(); %> />
```

I.e. assigning attributes.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639250/inline-code-on-webform-property

Answer (score 1):

This will work for databound controls, e.g.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text="<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" />
```

Then in your code behind, you'll need to call `lbl.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text='<%=DateTime.Now.ToString()%>' />
```