# javascript error when referencing Master-pages ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I have getting a javascript error when attempting to reference an object in a ContentPlaceHolder that is outside the current ContentPlaceHolder (they are both on the same child page).

The error is:  **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined**

The script line where the error occurs is:

```
    <input type="submit" name="Master$cphMainContent$btnUnregister" value="Proceed" onclick="document.getElementById('Master_cphHeadContent_TimeAlert').value = GetSeconds(); return ValidateProvider(1);" id="cphMainContent_btnUnregister" class="netButton" />
```

The **TimeAlert** is a hidden object in the **cphHeadContent** ContentPlaceHodler.

Usually, I would know that the object (TimeAlert) is not visible when it is being called. However, this time it's the same page, so I can't figure out why the object is null or undefined.

Any suggestions how to resolve this error?

Comment: Are you sure the control you are referring to has got *id* exactly as you specified it? When using java script try to reference controls with their *ClientID* property instead of hardcoding it in the script. More information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx. In order to do this, you can use **<%=** and **%>** like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889035/inline-code-in-markup-page-in-asp-net-webforms.

Comment: This is pre-existing code that is supposed to be working (except it's not working when I am running it)

Comment: I suppose *id* as available in java script can be dependent on where a control is in the structure of the page. If *id* of the control is hardcoded and something has changed in the page structure the code may stop working because the control has got now another *id*. In your browser open page's source and verify if control with this *id* is there. If it's not there, you can update *id* to a valid value, but using **Control.ClientID** instead would probably be a better solution.

Comment: What are the type of TimeAlert object? Is it a HiddenField? Are you sure this object have a value property? Can you post the HTML generated code of this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting the component ID on eventhandler?

Look at eventhandler:

```
document.getElementById(&#39;Master_cphHeadContent_TimeAlert&#39;).value = GetSeconds(); return ValidateProvider(1);
```

Note &#39 is a HTML encoded char, here is proprably your problem. Try it:

```
document.getElementById('Master_cphHeadContent_TimeAlert').value = GetSeconds(); return ValidateProvider(1);
```

Comment: Actually that was a typo on my part. I coped & pasted the code from debug mode (when I get the javascript error msgbox). The actualy code is with an apostrophe, not HTML encoded char.